# Pandas change month while calculating the corresponding last business day

Tags: python, pandas

In the below `pandas` dataframe example, `MyDate` consists of the ***1st day of the month*** and the  ***last business day*** of the month. The dataset will always run to 1st of `(current month - 1)`.

I would like to dynamically increase MyDate by one month. In doing so however, the last business day is no longer the correct one. As such, I would also like to calculate the last business day based on the updated month.

**Input:**

```
MyDate       MyValue 
31/Mar/2020  0
01/Apr/2020  a
30/Apr/2020  b
01/May/2020  c
29/May/2020  d <<< note 29 May - last workday of month
01/Jun/2020  e
30/Jun/2020  f
01/Jul/2020  g
31/Jul/2020  h
01/Aug/2020  i
```

**Desired output:**

```
MyDate       MyValue 
30/Apr/2020  0
01/May/2020  a
29/May/2020  b <<< note 29 May - last workday of month
01/Jun/2020  c
30/Jun/2020  d 
01/Jul/2020  e
31/Jul/2020  f
01/Aug/2020  g
31/Aug/2020  h
01/Sep/2020  i
```

I've broken down the problem into two parts:

1. Change `month` to `month+1` - using `relativedelta`
2. Get last business day for changed month - using `pd.offsets.BMonthEnd()`

, but somehow I am stuck at #2 although I have attempted similar solutions posted on stackoverflow.

**This is my code:**

```
import pandas as pd
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta

...
# this solves part #1
df['MyDate']=df['MyDate'].dt.date + relativedelta(months=+1)

# attempt at solving part 2
df['MyDate']=pd.to_datetime(df['MyDate'])

mask = df['MyDate'].dt.day > 1
df.loc[mask, 'MyDate'] = df['MyDate'] + pd.offsets.BMonthEnd(1)
```

The last line is where I am stuck; obviously it does not generate the results I thought it would...

Any help with solving this, or a different "pandas-esque" approach of solving the problem as a whole, would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may create a boolean mask to identify Business-month-end dates in your `MyDate` columns (Business-month-end dates returns `True`, others returns `False`). Use this mask to adding 1 month-begin and 1 business-month-end separately

```
m = df.MyDate == (df.MyDate + pd.offsets.BMonthEnd(0))
df.loc[m, 'MyDate']  = df.loc[m, 'MyDate'] +  pd.offsets.BMonthEnd(1)
df.loc[~m, 'MyDate'] = df.loc[~m, 'MyDate'] +  pd.offsets.MonthBegin(1)

print(df)

Output:
      MyDate MyValue
0 2020-04-30       0
1 2020-05-01       a
2 2020-05-29       b
3 2020-06-01       c
4 2020-06-30       d
5 2020-07-01       e
6 2020-07-31       f
7 2020-08-01       g
8 2020-08-31       h
9 2020-09-01       i
```

---

**Note**: I assume your `MyDate` column is already in `dtype: datetime64[ns]`